# How to link with a library built using Meson custom_target()?

Tags: meson-build

I'm using Meson [custom_target()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#custom_target) to build a 3rd party `foobar` library:

```
foobar_ct = custom_target('foobar_build',
                   command: `script.sh`,
                   output: 'foobar.a')
```

The custom target calls my script, which in turn calls Make to use existing Makefiles to build the lib. The custom_target() is used as a **subproject**, and the resulting output file ends up located at `./subprojects/foobar/foobar.a`.

When I try to link with it

```
foobar_dep = dependency('foobar', fallback:...)

exe = executable(
  'test',
  'main.c',
  dependencies: [foobar_dep]
  ...)
```

Meson gives me error:

`builddir/subprojects/foobar/foobar.a: No such file or directory`

How would I link with the `foobar.a`? Meson expects it at the build directory `./builddir/subprojects/foobar/foobar.a` - would it be a proper solution just to add a copy step to my script which would copy foobar.a from the place where Make built it, into the builddir?

Answer (score 0):

This reply is a little late but hopefully still helps. I had the same problem and the following did work for me:

```
foobar_ct = custom_target('foobar_build',
                   command: `script.sh`,
                   output: 'foobar.a')
foobar_dep= declare_dependency (sources: foobar_ct)
exe = executable(
  'test',
  'main.c',
  dependencies: [foobar_dep]
  ...)
```

Comment: Quick note, you don't need to wrap your custom target into a dependency here. You can add it in to the source list to `executable()`, e.g. `executable('test', 'main.c', foobar_ct, ...)`